# Kubernetes master node DNS unable discover service name

Tags: kubernetes

I have two nodes, master and slave. They actually working well except one thing. The master node unable to discover service name. The slave nodes are working perfect without issue.

I have installed the dnstools docker on both nodes. 
Their /etc/resolv.conf files are exactly same.

```
root@pvgl50934100b:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME                              STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
my-master   Ready    master   84d   v1.13.2
pvgl50934100b                     Ready    <none>   17h   v1.13.2

root@pvgl50934100b:~# kubectl  get pods -o wide | grep dnstools
dnstools-5c57c4d457-695hs                     1/1     Running   16         16h   10.244.12.13   pvgl50934100b                     <none>           <none>
dnstools-5c57c4d457-fvhts                     1/1     Running   15         15h   10.244.0.125   my-master   <none>           <none>
```

```
root@pvgl50934100b:~# kubectl  exec dnstools-5c57c4d457-695hs -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.244.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5

root@pvgl50934100b:~# kubectl  exec dnstools-5c57c4d457-fvhts -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.244.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

My endpoint configuration:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Endpoints
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2019-01-24T10:05:42Z"
    labels:
      addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
      k8s-app: kube-dns
      kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
      kubernetes.io/name: CoreDNS
    name: kube-dns
    namespace: kube-system
    resourceVersion: "9725462"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/kube-dns
    uid: 9bc1c68d-1fbf-11e9-a68f-4ccc6a74038f
  subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.244.0.124
      nodeName: my-master
      targetRef:
        kind: Pod
        name: coredns-779bd65884-8m4j4
        namespace: kube-system
        resourceVersion: "9725461"
        uid: f2fda560-5ab1-11e9-a68f-4ccc6a74038f
    - ip: 10.244.12.15
      nodeName: pvgl50934100b
      targetRef:
        kind: Pod
        name: coredns-779bd65884-488s2
        namespace: kube-system
        resourceVersion: "9725429"
        uid: eedbd034-5ab1-11e9-a68f-4ccc6a74038f
    ports:
    - name: dns
      port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - name: dns-tcp
      port: 53
      protocol: TCP
```

My service:

```
kube-dns                NodePort   10.244.0.10      <none>        53:30765/UDP,53:30765/TCP   75d
```

The testing result by dig:

```
root@pvgl50934100b:~# kubectl  exec dnstools-5c57c4d457-695hs -- dig -t Mx kubernetes

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3 <<>> -t Mx kubernetes
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 12552
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kubernetes.            IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           30  IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2019040903 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 137 msec
;; SERVER: 10.244.0.10#53(10.244.0.10)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 10 02:02:17 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114

root@pvgl50934100b:~# kubectl  exec dnstools-5c57c4d457-fvhts -- dig -t Mx kubernetes

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3 <<>> -t Mx kubernetes
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
command terminated with exit code 9
```

I am not sure what else tools or place I can use to check the configuration. 
Expecting the master node is getting same result as slave.

Any suggestions / advice will appreciate.

Comment: It is **very suspicious** that your Pod on the master is assigned the same subnet as the kubernetes DNS Service (`10.244.0.125` for the Pod, `10.244.0.10` for kube-dns, versus `10.244.12.13` for the other Pod); that might also indicate a CNI misconfiguration, which will do all kinds of weird stuff, just like you are experiencing

Comment: Hi, I am not able to get why the same subnet will cause problem. 
On master node, also the pod will run on master, it will inherit from master node as below:
cni0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:58:0a:f4:00:01
          inet addr:10.244.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0

Same to slave:
root@pvgl50934100b:/# ifconfig
cni0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:58:0a:f4:0c:01
          inet addr:10.244.12.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0

No?

Comment: By **The master node unable to discover service name** do you mean that `kubectl get svc` from master node doesn't work? Sorry, I just don't see it in your post

Comment: No @A_Suh, the kubectl get svc is working on master. But you see the dnstool, the dig or nslookup is not able to resolve. All the pods not working on master nodes. All same replicated pods on slave nodes are working well.

Comment: Do you have svc name kubernetes ?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian Ye, otherwise how the other pod works?

Comment: @AlanSun because traditionally the Pod CIDR and the Service CIDR are distinct, since Pod IPs are actual addresses given out by CNI but **Service** addresses exist only in iptables/ipvs. So can't prove it is wrong, just suspicious

Comment: Can you try with FQDN(fully qualified domain name). `dig kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian, same result and same error only on master node pod. I am wondering anything else I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no sure how it comes, However I re-init the master again and everything works fine, as long as two coredns run on two different nodes. Both can use the dig and return correct response.